# Changing QWidget object scope changes the CSS

Tags: c++, qt, qstylesheet

Consider this two parts of code

1. `NotifWidget* notifWidget_ = new NotifWidget();
    notifWidget_->show();
    notifWidget_->move(computePosition(notifWidget_));`
2. `notifWidget_->show();
    notifWidget_->move(computePosition(notifWidget_));`

In first case the `NotifWidget` (which is inherited from `QFrame`) the `notifWidget_` object is local object and the corresponding widget is show like this

[image: qframe with local object]

In the second case the `notifWidget_` object is the class member and and here is the image for that case

[image: qframe member object]

Both widgets have same CSS style sheet and same `objectName`. Does anyone know what's the problem for the second case? Why in second case the inner widgets are overlapped?

**update**

including css(if any)

```
QWidget#NotifWidget_actions
{
    border:0px solid;
}
QWidget#AccessGiven, QWidget#AccessGiven[onhover="false"]
{
    background: white;
}
QWidget#AccessGiven[onhover="true"]
{
    background: #f2f2f2;
}

QLabel#AccessGiven_icon, QLabel#AccessGiven_message, QLabel#AccessGiven_icon[onhover="false"], QLabel#AccessGiven_message[onhover="false"]
{
    background: white;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    qproperty-wordWrap: true;
    max-height: 48px;
    min-height: 48px;
}
QLabel#AccessGiven_message
{
    font: 12px;
    max-width: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
}
QLabel#AccessGiven_icon
{
    max-width: 64px;
    min-width: 64px;
}
QLabel#AccessGiven_icon[onhover="true"], QLabel#AccessGiven_message[onhover="true"]
{
    background: #f2f2f2;
}

QPushButton#AccessGiven_action, QPushButton#AccessGiven_action[onhover="true"]
{
    font: 12px;
    color: rgba( 35, 35, 35, 0% );
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    background-color: rgba( 35, 35, 35, 0% );
    margin-left: 0px;
}
QPushButton#AccessGiven_action[onhover="true"]
{
    color: rgba( 35, 35, 35, 50% );
}

QPushButton#AccessGiven_action:hover
{
    background: rgba( 35, 35, 35, 20% );
}
QPushButton#AccessGiven_action:pressed
{
    background: rgba( 35, 35, 35, 10% );
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
QPushButton#NotifWidget_settings
{
    background-image: url(./media/settings.png);
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    border: 0px;
}
QPushButton#NotifWidget_settings:hover
{ 
    background-color: lightgray;
}
QPushButton#NotifWidget_settings:pressed
{ 
background-color: silver;
}

QPushButton#NotifWidget_help
{
    background-image: url(./media/help.png);
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    border: 0px;
}
QPushButton#NotifWidget_help:hover
{ 
    background-color: lightgray;
}
QPushButton#NotifWidget_help:pressed
{ 
    background-color: silver;
}

QPushButton#NotifWidget_toWeb
{
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    background-image: url(./media/web.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;;
    border: 0px light ;
}
QPushButton#NotifWidget_toWeb:hover
{
    background-color: lightgray;
}
QPushButton#NotifWidget_toWeb:pressed
{
    background-color: silver;
}

QPushButton#NotifWidget_exit
{
    height: 14;
    padding:2px;
    margin-left:5px;
    background-color: rgb(255,0,0, 0%);
    border: 1px light ;
}
QPushButton#NotifWidget_exit:hover
{
    background-color: rgb(255,0,0, 25%);
}
QPushButton#NotifWidget_exit:pressed
{
    background-color: rgb(255,0,0, 35%);
}
QScrollArea#NotifWidget_scrollArea
{
/*    background: transparent;
    border: 0px solid;*/
}
QFrame#NotifWidget
{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    /*min-width: 345;
    max-width: 345;
    min-height: 400;*/
    border: 1px solid rgb(37, 76, 241);
}
```

Comment: May you please include the corresponding lines of the stylesheet? I've had problems sometimes when reparenting and had to duplicate the CSS to contemplate both cases (not sure why, sorry).

Comment: @cbuchart i've added css, but there is lots of elements